# Python BeautifulSoup cannot find the data in the page source

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

in this website I can see the data I want and when I inspect the element I find it ,however it is not there in the page source so I cannot scrape it :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
from lxml import html
import requests
import MySQLdb
import urllib2
import itertools
import re
import sys
from datetime import date, timedelta as td


urls =("http://euw.lolesports.com/tourney/match/1833")
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(urls,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
tournament=soup.findAll('div',{'class':['field-item even']})
print tournament
print soup.title.text
match_time=soup.findAll('span',{'class':['local-time']})
for tag in match_time:
    time=tag.get('datetime',None)
    if time !=None:
        print time
vid = soup.findAll('iframe',{'class':['media-youtube-player']})
for tag in vid:
    vidlink=tag.get('href',None)
    if vidlink !=None:
        print vidlink
teams=soup.findAll('h5',{'class':['team-name']})
for tag in teams:
    tag.replaceWith('')
    print (tag.string)
    print soup.findAll('span',{'class':['winner-holder']})
```

I was able to retrieve the title and teams but with everything else no luck, when I click on each element to inspect it I can see the data there, however when I view the page source they are empty tags which is why I think I am not getting any results. 
Is there a way to overcome this ?

Comment: In _which_ website? We have no idea what's you're trying to do, or what are you trying to get. Please be clear.

Comment: The website is in urls= what I am trying to get is when you go to the website there are 2 teams 1 has -winner next to it I want to scrape that as well as the time of the match and the video link

Comment: Look to see what requests the web page is making using the Network tab or equivalent of your browser's developer tools. Alternatively, read the JavaScript on the page to determine how it fetches it.

Comment: I think that will work only for the videos since its a button and need clicking to get the request but the rest are just text in the page. also I am not really good with JavaScript

Comment: I was able to print the time and date just now I am only missing the video and -winner now